# Inserting my image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I had a PHP file that properly generates an image that I need. In my main page, there is a link named "View Image". So I put an < a href > tag in the "View Image" so that when it is clicked the image will load. However, when "View Image" was clicked, the whole page will load the image, which is not what I wanted. How will I code it in such a way that it will be just a part my page (e.g. just a small image within the site, not the whole webpage)?

Thanks!

Comment: did u try using javascript for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `<img>` tag to embed the image inside of the page.

```
<img src="path/to/img.png">
```

Instead of linking to it.

Comment: thanks! I did not know that <img src> a php file will work.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//HTML
<a href="" onclick="return disp();">Show Image</a>
<div id="pre" >
     <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>

//Javascript

<script type="text/javascript" >
   document.getElementById("pre").style.display="none";
   function disp()
   {
       if(document.getElementById("pre").style.display="none")
       {
           document.getElementById("pre").style.display="";
       }
       else
       {
           document.getElementById("pre").style.display="none";
       }
       return false;
    }
</script>
```